# Inserting values to sqlite table results in error: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT] Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed: salesman.code)

Tags: java, sqlite, csv

I have created a fully-functional java app with mysql db. I have to change the mysql db to sqlite db to make the app more portable (no installation required). I'm in the process of converting all my mysql tables and values to sqlite.

I was to create the database and tables and now, I'm populating my `salesman` table from a .csv file selected by the user through FileChooser. After the user selects .csv file that would populate the `salesman` table, NetBeans would result to this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed: salesman.code)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:901)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:810)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:847)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:86)
```

After researching for similar problems, it would mean that the values I'm putting in the `salesman` table are not aligned with the parameters / constraint set with the `salesman` table. But when I created the table, I did not put any `UNIQUE` constraint. I made the table using Browser for SQLite and this is the code for creating database and tables:

```
 try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sandapp.db");
        String createSalesmanQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salesman (\n" +
                "    code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY\n" +
                "                 NOT NULL,\n" +
                "    name TEXT    NOT NULL\n" +
                ")\n" +
                "WITHOUT ROWID;";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(createSalesmanQuery);
        ps.executeUpdate();

        String emptySalesmanQuery = "DELETE FROM salesman;"; //empties if there are contents
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(emptySalesmanQuery);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

The constraint `WITHOUT ROWID` is there because the attribute `code` are coming from another database, so there shouldn't be a table id that auto-increments. I already checked the .csv file where all the values for column `codes` are and there are no repeating values. This file was also used for mysql db and it uploaded successfully.  Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Here is my method that gets the salesman details from a .csv file

```
public static String getSalesmanFromFile(String filePath){
    ArrayList<Salesman> salesmanList= new ArrayList<Salesman>();
    String status = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line = null;
        String[] strSalesman = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection connection =  DBConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = null;

            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null){
                strSalesman = line.split(",");
                salesmanList.add(new Salesman(Integer.parseInt(strSalesman[0]), strSalesman[1]));

                String insertSalesmanQuery = "INSERT INTO salesman VALUES(?, ?);";
                ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertSalesmanQuery);

                for(int i = 0; i<salesmanList.size(); i++){
                    ps.setInt(1, salesmanList.get(i).getCode());
                    ps.setString(2, salesmanList.get(i).getName());
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                status = "Successfully uploaded";
            }
            ps.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        status = "Error"; //- Please review file selected. Make sure that format is followed.";
        System.out.println(status);
    }
    return status;
```

Here are sample Salesman details from .csv file:

```
5099    JONATHAN REYES
5010    EDWIN DAVID
```

These two values return the error stated above in the Output  log in NetBeans.

Comment: WITHOUT ROWID is pointless when the primary key is INTEGER. A primary key always is unique. Anyway, why are you using UPDATE instead of INSERT?

Comment: @CL removed the WITHOUT ROWID after researching again. I'm not using UPDATE tho. I'll edit my post with my INSERT code